# React-Native, JustifyContent: flex-end and space-around acting strangely

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get a circular view in the middle of a container view (vertically). If I use justifyContent: flex-start, the top of the circle touches the top of the container (as expected). If I use flex-end, the circle goes just below where it should be - i.e. it looks as if the center of the circle is at the bottom of the container, or there is a small shift/margin down. If I try space-around or center, the circle is just off center (i.e. it is an average of flex-start and flex-end, but unfortunately this is not what I require as flex-end is acting unexpectedly). I have tried playing around with margins etc of containers without any luck - any help would be appreciated. The specific lines of code are at the bottom, but here is my full Component for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, Image, Button, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../firebase.js';



class Auth extends Component {

  state = {
    username: "",
    email:"",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword:"",

    error: {
      username:"",
      email: "",
      password:"",
      confirmPassword:""
    },

    focus: {
      username: false,
      email: false,
      password: false,
      confirmPassword: false
    },

    placeholder:{
      username: "Choose Username",
      email: "Enter Email",
      password: "Choose Password",
      confirmPassword: "Confirm Password"
    },

    validation:{
      username:{
        min:7,
        max:15,
        unique: false
      },
      password:{
        min:7,
        max:15
      }
    }
  }

  onChangeUsername = (event) => {

    var oldError = {...this.state.error};

    if(this.state.validation.username.unique===true)
    {oldError.username = "This username is already taken"}

    else if((event.nativeEvent.text.length<this.state.validation.username.min) || (event.nativeEvent.text.length>this.state.validation.username.max) )
    {oldError.username = "Username should be between " + this.state.validation.username.min + " and " + this.state.validation.username.max + " characters" ;
  console.log(oldError);
  console.log(this.state.error);}

    else oldError.username = "";

    this.setState({ username: event.nativeEvent.text, error:oldError })
  }

  onChangeEmail = (event) => {
    this.setState({ email: event.nativeEvent.text })
  }

  onChangePassword = (event) => {
    var oldError = {...this.state.error};

    if ((event.nativeEvent.text.length<this.state.validation.password.min) || (event.nativeEvent.text.length>this.state.validation.password.max))
    {oldError.password = "Password should be between " + this.state.validation.password.min + " and " + this.state.validation.password.max + " characters" ;}

    else {oldError.password = ""};

    this.setState({ password: event.nativeEvent.text, error: oldError })
  }

  onChangeConfirmPassword = (event) => {
    var oldError = {...this.state.error};

    if (this.state.password !== event.nativeEvent.text)
    {oldError.confirmPassword = "Passwords do not match";
 }

    else {oldError.confirmPassword = ""};
    console.log(this.state.error);
    this.setState({ confirmPassword: event.nativeEvent.text, error:oldError })

  }
  createUser = () => {




  if(this.state.error.username !== false || this.state.error.email !== false || this.state.error.password !== false || this.state.error.password !== false)

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password).catch(error => {

      var errorCode = error.code;
      var oldError = {...this.state.error};

      if (errorCode === "auth/invalid-email") { oldError.email = "Invalid email address" }
      else if (errorCode === "auth/weak-password") { oldError.password = "Password should be between " + this.state.validation.password.min + " and " + this.state.validation.password.max + " characters" }
      else if (errorCode === "auth/email-already-in-use") { oldError.email = "This email is already registered"}
    });




    }

  userLogIn = () => {

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password).catch(error => {

      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      console.log("hello");
      if (errorCode === "auth/invalid-email") { this.setState({ error: "Invalid email or password." }) }
      else if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") { this.setState({ error: "Invalid email or password." }) }
      else if (errorCode === "auth/user-not-found") { this.setState({ error: "Invalid email or password." }) }
      console.log(error.code);
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <ImageBackground  source={require('../../Images/back8.gif')}  resizeMode="cover" style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#eeeeee", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "flex-start" }}>
      <View style={{width:"100%",height:"30%", margin: -20, flexDirection: "row", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"space-around"}}>
     <Image  source={require('../../Images/Logo.png')} style={{width: "60%", height: "100%" }} resizeMode= "contain" ></Image>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: "80%", height: "10%", margin: "2%", backgroundColor:"transparent",flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center", alignContent:"center"}}>
        <TextInput
         value={this.state.username}
         underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
         autoCorrect={false}
         spellCheck={false}
         onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
         style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"white", padding: "5%", margin: "2%", letterSpacing:2, borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: this.state.focus.username?"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)":"black" }}
         placeholder={this.state.placeholder.username}
         placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
         selectionColor= "white"
         autoComplete={"off"}
         textAlign={'center'}
         onFocus={()=>{this.setState({ focus: {
          username: true,
          email: false,
          password: false,
          confirmPassword: false
        }})}}
        />
        </View>
<Text style={{color:"white"}}>{this.state.error.username}</Text>
<View style={{ width: "80%", height: "10%", margin: "2%", backgroundColor:"transparent",flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center", alignContent:"center"}}>
<View style={{backgroundColor:"green", height:"100%", margin: "2%", width: 20, flexDirection: "column",justifyContent:"space-around"}}>
<View style={{backgroundColor:"#00ff7f", margin: 0, height:20, width: 20, borderRadius:50}}></View>
</View>
<TextInput
         value={this.state.email}
         autoCorrect={false}
         spellCheck={false}
         onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
         style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"white", padding: "5%", margin: "2%", letterSpacing:2, borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: this.state.focus.email?"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)":"black" }}
         placeholder={this.state.placeholder.email}
         selectionColor= "white"
         underlineColorAndroid= 'transparent'
         placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
         autoComplete={"off"}
         textAlign={'center'}
         onFocus={()=>{this.setState({ focus: {
          username: false,
          email: true,
          password: false,
          confirmPassword: false
        }})}}
        />
        <View style={{backgroundColor:"#00ff7f", margin: "2%", height:20, width: 20, borderRadius:50}}></View>
        </View>
<Text style={{color:"white"}}>{this.state.error.email}</Text>
<View style={{ width: "80%", height: "10%", margin: "2%", backgroundColor:"transparent",flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center", alignContent:"center"}}>
<TextInput
         value={this.state.password}
         autoCorrect={false}
         spellCheck={false}
         onChange={this.onChangePassword}
         style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"white", padding: "5%", margin: "2%", letterSpacing:2, borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: this.state.focus.password?"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)":"black" }}
         placeholder={this.state.placeholder.password}
         placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
         selectionColor= "white"
         autoComplete={"off"}
         textAlign={'center'}
         secureTextEntry = {true}
         onFocus={()=>{this.setState({ focus: {
          username: false,
          email: false,
          password: true,
          confirmPassword: false
        }})}}
        />
        </View>
<Text style={{color:"white"}}>{this.state.error.password}</Text>
<View style={{ width: "80%", height: "10%", margin: "2%", backgroundColor:"transparent",flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center", alignContent:"center"}}>
<TextInput
         value={this.state.confirmPassword}
         autoCorrect={false}
         spellCheck={false}
         onChange={this.onChangeConfirmPassword}
         selectionColor= "white"
         style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"white", padding: "5%", margin: "2%", letterSpacing:2, borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: this.state.focus.confirmPassword?"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)":"black" }}
         placeholder={this.state.placeholder.confirmPassword}
         placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
         autoComplete={"off"}
         textAlign={'center'}
         secureTextEntry = {true}
         onFocus={()=>{this.setState({ focus: {
          username: false,
          email: false,
          password: false,
          confirmPassword: true
        }})}}
        />
        </View>
      <Text style={{color:"white"}}>{this.state.error.confirmPassword}</Text>
        <View style={{width: "60%", height: "20%", margin: "2%", borderRadius: 20, marginTop: "4%"}}>
        <Button title="Sign Up" style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", padding: "2%"}} onPress={this.createUser}></Button>
        </View>
        <View style={{width: "20%", height: "20%", margin: "-10%", borderRadius: 20}}>
        <Button title="Sign In" style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", padding: "2%"}} onPress={this.userSignIn}></Button>
        </View>

        <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "20%" }}></View>
      </ImageBackground>



    );

  }
}


export default Auth;
```

Here is the circle container and circle within the above code (when rendering the InputText for email):

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:"green", height:"100%", margin: "2%", width: 20, flexDirection: "column",justifyContent:"space-around"}}>
<View style={{backgroundColor:"#00ff7f", margin: 0, height:20, width: 20, borderRadius:50}}></View>
</View>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you put this code in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: Could you post some screenshots? I can't figure out what is wrong. I just tried and the styling seems ok for me